# Top-most and Bottom-most Horizontal Divider does not show up in ListView

Tags: android, android-widget

I am using a ListView. But the top-most and bottom-most horizontal bar does not show up. Why? I am using this:

```
android:divider="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright"
```

Comment: Have you found a good solution for this problem? android:footerDividersEnabled doesn't work for me.

Comment: umm, sorry never tried beyond that :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you looked into setting `android:headerDividersEnabled` and `android:footerDividersEnabled` on the `ListView`?

Also, if you look for `drawDivider` in [platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widger/ListView.java](http://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java) in the [Android open source repository](http://android.googlesource.com), you'll be able to find some more clues.

Comment: In a widget, it appears android:footerDividersEnabled and android:headerDividersEnabled does nothing. Still looking for other solutions.

Comment: I have three headers in my listview, the third header is supposed to be show/hide on run time. Is there any way to remove the third header's divider height (i.e set to 0) or any workaround?

Answer (score 11):

Add a dummy footer and header

```
listViewContato = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_contatos);
listViewContato.addHeaderView(new View(getActivity()));
listViewContato.addFooterView(new View(getActivity()));
```

Comment: this needs more love, it works! Footer as mentioned previously in Roman Nurik's comment thread, works right away, but header does require a header.

Answer (score 10):

Here's how I implemented it...
Bottom divider shows up after setting `android:paddingBottom` for the `ListView`. BUT in my case after setting `android:paddingTop` top and bottom dividers are not showing. I don't know why.
So I added in my `list_item_layout.xml` the following code:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
```

and in my adapter I just changing the visibility of this view:

```
View topDivider = v.findViewById(R.id.divider);

if (position == 0) {
    topDivider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    topDivider.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Hope this will helpfull to someone.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with [LibSlideMenu](https://github.com/bk138/LibSlideMenu).

As `android:headerDividersEnabled` set to true did not show the header divider in the Sliding Menu, I solved it by changing `slidemenu.xml` (not `slidemenu_listitem.xml`) to

```
<LinearLayout ...>

    <LinearLayout ...>
    <ImageView ...>  (this is the header image on top of the menu)

    <View
    android:layout_width="250dip"
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:background="@drawable/divider" />

    <ListView ...> (this is the ListView for the MenuItems)
    </LinearLayout>


    <FrameLayout ...>
    </FrameLayout ...>
</LinearLayout>
```

This will add the divider manually.

Answer (score 0):

First you'll have to enable the footerDividers in XML:

```
android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
```

Then simply add a dummy footer view like this

```
listview.addFooterView(new View(this), null, false);
```

You can do the same for header